# In React script, using '/' in </h1> makes the rest of the line a comment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Here</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm trying to get into React, and the first thing I do gets a problem. The slash(/) for the render first component will comment out the line. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your editors syntax highlighting, what editor are you using?

Comment: JSX is not JavaScript, you need babel to transpile it to JavaScript. You can create a project with [create react app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Comment: I use Sublime and the syntax is in Javascript. I also put `type="text/babel"` when sourcing the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed HMR with the node create React app thing. I'm unsure of how it worked but the app seems to work now with node.

Answer (score 0):

What editor are you using ?

It usually means your IDE doesnt know you're using jsx and parses the code as plain js.

Try changing your file extension to `.jsx` if it is not already and re-opening your file.

Comment: A quick google search brought me to https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime

You should check it out

Comment: I changed the file to .jsx, but it still gave me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` 

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>React Website</title>
</head>
<div id="root"></div>
<body>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>>
 <script src="script.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which file have you renamed ? this looks like an `index.html` file.

Comment: I renamed the script.jsx file that the Html referenced to. However, in the sources of the debug menu, it didn't see the script file as one of the sources. I'm still confused over why but found using node to [create a template app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)  worked for me.